# Problem with swfobject_api or jwplayer module

Tags: files

I have a problem with swfobject_api or jwplayer module.

When I use this code in node.tpl.php everything is fine.

```
$config='sample';
$flashVars=array( 'file' => 'path to flv' );
print theme('jwplayermodule_render_player', $config, $flashVars);
```

When I use this code in front-page.tpl.php the code is not working.

In node-tpl.php this JavaScript is added.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/projects/theme/sites/all/modules/drupal/jwplayermodule/jwplayermodule_jwembedder.js?c"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--//--><![CDATA[//><!--
jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "jwplayer": { "files": { "jwplayer-1": { "flashplayer": "http://localhost/projects/theme/sites/default/files/jwplayermodule/player/player.swf", "width": "400", "height": "280", "controlbar": "bottom", "wmode": "opaque", "file": "/projects/theme/sites/default/files/1057680_0.flv", "config": "http://localhost/projects/theme/sites/default/files/jwplayermodule/configs/sample.xml", "events": [  ] } } } });
//--><!]]>
</script>
```

In front-page.tpl.php, it is not added.

I put `<?php print $closure ?>` in footer.php, and included it in front-page.tpl.php and node.tpl.php.

Comment: what is output for front-page.tpl.php? nothing? if nothing are you sure front-page.tpl.php registered correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your template file should be called page-front.tpl.php, not front-page.tpl.php. Once you've renamed it flush your caches and it will work!